# adding a node in Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am currently working on implementing a `Binary search tree` but I have a problem with creating the `add_node()` function. I tried to make it in a recursive way, but the result was weird.

For example- If I run `add_node(1)`, `add_node(5)`, and `add_node(0)`, my tree has only 1, no 5 and 0.

I would be happy if you tell me what the problem is.

```
def add_node(self, value: int) -> None:
        
    if self.root == None:
        self.root = Node(value)
        return

    else:
        return self.add_recursion(self.root, value)

def add_recursion(self, node: Node, value: int) -> None:
        
    if node == None:
        node = Node(value)
        return

    elif value < node.value:
        return self.add_recursion(node.left, value)

    else:
        return self.add_recursion(node.right, value)
```

Comment: please provide more code.the `node.left` `node.right` it not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `None` value is passed into a function, it is passed by value, not by reference, since... there is no reference.

```
    elif value < node.value:
        return self.add_recursion(node.left, value)

    else:
        return self.add_recursion(node.right, value)
```

When `node.left` or `node.right` is `None`, a Node ends up being created but not attached to `node`.
So what you could do is handle the cases where they are `None` separately.

```
def add_recursion(self, node: Node, value: int) -> None:
    if node == None:
        node = Node(value)
    elif value < node.value:
        if node.left == None:
            node.left = Node(value)
        else:
            self.add_recursion(node.left, value)
    else:
        if node.right == None:
            node.right = Node(value)
        else:
            self.add_recursion(node.right, value)
```

While this is workable, it becomes quite ugly. Look at the answer by Locke to see a better way to structure your code.

Also, an additional tip for readability, avoid using `return` where they aren't necessary such as at the end of a flow.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how you handle if `node.left` or `node.right` does not exist. Since the arguments are copied for each call, setting the value of `node` in `add_recursion` has no effect on the tree.

```py
def foo(val):
    print("foo start:", val)
    val = 5
    print("foo end:", val)

bar = 3
foo(bar)  # Value of bar is copied for call
print("after foo:", bar) # Prints bar is still 3
```

I think you might also be getting confused due to how the root node is handled. Here is some starter code on how can handle the initial call to `add_recursive`.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def add_recursive(self, value: int):
        # TODO: recursively add to left or right
        # For example, here is how you could recursively make a linked list
        if self.right is None:
            self.right = Node(value)
        else:
            self.right.add_recursive(value)

class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def add_node(self, value: int):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(value)
        else:
            # Call add_recursive on root instead of with root.
            self.root.add_recursive(value)

tree = BinarySearchTree()
tree.add_node(1)
tree.add_node(5)
tree.add_node(0)
```